# Shared function which depends on $ionicPopup?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a custom version of message box in ionic. The function uses `$ionicPopup`.

```
$myShowPopup = function() {
 $scope.data = {};
 $ionicPopup.show({
   subTitle: 'There is no network connection right now.',
   scope: $scope,
   buttons: [
     { text: 'Got it' 
     type: 'button clear'},
   ]});
}
```

I will need the function be called in multiple places, e.g., in following code of app.js. Where it should be defined?

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        ......
        // Need to call it here
        ......
})
.config(function ($resourceProvider) {
    angular.forEach($resourceProvider.defaults.actions, function (action) {
        action['interceptor'] = {
            responseError: function (httpResponse) {
                ......
                // And here.
                ......
            }
        };
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sound like best practice to use a `service`. However, there's a hack to do in order to be dependent on in in the `app.config()` stage - the `service` defined as `provider`.

**Online demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/jdDPepAbn9UXkdVsDR5L?p=preview**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ionic']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.test = function(){
    $http.get('http://asdasd.does-not-exist');  
  }

});


app.run(function($ionicPlatform, interactiveService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    interactiveService.showPopup('Welcome!');
  });
});


app.provider('interactiveService', function() {
  this.$get = ['$ionicPopup', function($ionicPopup) {

    return {
      showPopup: showPopup
    };

    function showPopup(message) {

      $ionicPopup.show({
        subTitle: message,
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Got it',
          type: 'button clear'
        }, ]
      });
    }
  }];
});


app.config(function($provide, $httpProvider) {
  $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {
    return {
      response: function(response) {
        return response || $q.when(response);
      },
      responseError: function(rejection) {

        var interactiveService = $injector.get('interactiveService');

        if (rejection.status === 0 || rejection.status === -1) {
          interactiveService.showPopup('There is no network connection right now.');
        }

        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: I tried it on phone. However, it popup the message on every webapi calls and no data was received?

Comment: Thanks. However, it still popup once at beginning?

Comment: I removed it. The message is still shown. The status code is 0.

Comment: probably because of http failure. to detect why - check the server logs or use an http debugger (like fiddler) and investigate to know why you receiving http error responses.

Comment: I see. I think there were some 404 error for some unimportant http call in the code. I should only capture the errors of the ngResource calls. Maybe I should create a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea to write a wrapper around the `$ionicPopup`. This way it should be really easy to provide default values and even give you a possibility to replace those defaults. Additional advantage lays in the fact that it's really easy to swap `$ionicPopup` with another pop-up implementation, if you ever need it.

Best way to write such a wrapper is to create an angular `service`.

```
angular.module('myPopup', ['ionic', '_'])
.service(function ($ionicPopup) {
    var service = {
        showPopup: showPopup
    }
    return service;

    function showPopup(options) {
        var settings = _.defaultsDeep(options, {
            subTitle: 'There is no network connection right now.',
            buttons: [
                { 
                    text: 'Got it' 
                    type: 'button clear'
                },
            ]
        });

        $ionicPopup.show(settings);
    }
})
```

As you can see i'm using [_.defaultsDeep](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_defaultsdeepobject-sources). This is useful, because you can provide showPopup with your own options, or default to something else if no options are given.

You would call the pop-up everywhere you need it by doing:

```
myPopup.showPopup();
```

With the possibility to add you own options, so if you want to override the subTitle, you would do the following:

```
var options = {
    subTitle: 'my custom subtitle'
};

myPopup.showPopup(options);
```

Comment: I see a valid comment by Jossef Harush about the fact you want to show a pop-up in config phase. I think it would be best if you could make a mix between my solution (especially the defaultsDeep) and his provider method.

Answer (score -1):

Create a factory for this function and wherever you need this function just inject and call the function. Another better solution can be is to create a directive for this  for the popup. You can reuse it easily.

Comment: it cant be injected in the `app.config()` stage, pretty sure OP need to show an interactive message on ajax failures as well as general failures and want to re-use that `showMessage` function

Comment: Thanks Jossef to correct me.But directive could be better solution.